# 2 AppCompatActivity Projects with different annotation suggestion for same code

Tags: java, android, android-studio, annotations

I have 2 Android Studio Projects with AppCompatActivity, same buildToolsVersion and compileSdkVersion.

In the first Project annotation works fine and insert @NonNull to Bundle state:
[image]

In the other Project the suggestion is as follows:
[image]

After inserting @RecentlyNonNull to Bundle outState i got the errormessage 'androidx.annotation.RecentlyNonNull' is not public in 'androidx.annotation'. Cannot be accessed from outside package. Shure, i can change the annotation to @NonNull but the question for me is, why are the suggestions different?

Comment: Did you solve this? I seem to have the same problem after migrating to Android Studio 4.0

Comment: No, not solved, problem still exists.